# how tow install the last version of TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, updates

I'm working with Ubuntu 14.04, and I have `tensorflow v0.10` installed. I want to update `tensorflow`. How can I do this?

I do not understand the process described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way todo this is

```
$ pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

After running this for python 2.7

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

for python 3.5

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

This is only for CPU processing. If you want to use a GPU you'll have to get different URLS from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#TF_PYTHON_URL

As well as install the necessary CUDA drivers including CUDNN.

Comment: Storing debug log for failure in /home/brm17/.pip/pip.log !

Comment: @Brm-Covißio what version of python are you using and what does that .log say?

Comment: @Brm-Covißio try setting `export TF_BINARY_URL=http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`   this time it's without the https

Comment: other method please   , i do thois : `export TF_BINARY_URL=http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux‌​/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.‌​0-cp27-none-linux_x8‌​6_64.whl` but

Answer (score 0):

I avoid issues while upgrading, I'd suggest uninstalling tensorflow first:

```
$ pip uninstall protobuf
$ pip uninstall tensorflow
```

and reinstall the latest version from here: http://tflearn.org/installation/